# apex:repeat not iterating for null value

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, css

> Corrected VF code:

```
<apex:pageBlock ><br/>

    <style>
    TABLE#showcells {
         empty-cells: show 
    }
    </style>

    <apex:outputpanel style="height:Auto;" layout="block">
        <table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="showcells">

            <thead class="rich-table-thead">
                <tr class="headerRow">
                    <td width="115px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="95px" align="center">Indicative OG</td>
                    <td width="95px" align="center">Indicative OU</td>
                    <td width="95px" align="center">Indicative CSG</td>
                    <td width="95px" align="center">Indicative Industry</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!Indicativ}" var="varQuarter">
                <tr>
                    <td class="datacell">{!varQuarter.Qrtr}</td>

                    <apex:repeat value="{!varQuarter.Value}" var="Value" >
                        <td class="datacell">{!Value}</td>
                    </apex:repeat> 

                </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </apex:outputpanel>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

And there is a class INSIDE extension such as:

```
    class arrayIndcValu{

        public String Qrtr              {get;set;}     
        public list<string> Value       {get;set;}

        public arrayIndcValu(){
            this.Qrtr = '';

            this.Value = new list<string>();
        }
    }
```

And "Indicativ" is a list of type of this above class:

```
    public list<arrayIndcValu> Indicativ        {get;set;}
```

"varQuarter" contains values of string like: `[PUNE, BANGALORE, NULL, DELHI]`
The problem is that for 3rd value, which is null in this array, dataCell is not getting rendered and instead, I get out put in 3 cells only for that row. The repeat iterates only 3 times and skips the null value, hence creating only 3 cells.

Output is like:

> PUNE BANGALORE DELHI [no cell rendered, blank space]

Output should be:

> PUNE BANGALORE  [empty cell] DELHI

How to render this empty cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible things you can do to assist yourself in handling this issue.

The first may not be necessary or will only be half of the solution to the problem. Try adding a null value check for `this.quarter` to your class method and if it's null, put `'&nbsp'` (a space) in it so the value won't be empty.

Most important will be to add the following to the CSS for your Table:

```
TABLE { empty-cells: show }
```

This will prevent the table cell from collapsing when the content is empty or only contains spaces.

**EDIT**

You will need to specify an Id for the Table and create your CSS as a Custom CSS Class that applies to that Id. Right now you have `class=list` Is that standard CSS? If not, add the property to that CSS. Otherwise, add the Id to the Table and adjust the CSS above to look something more like this:

```
TABLE#ShwEmptClls { empty-cells: show }
```

As in:

```
<table class="list" Id="ShwEmptClls">
```

Where ShwEmptClls will be the Id of the Table and must be specified in your markup. I would take the other in-line mark-up and add it to your styleclass as well so that it looked like this:

```
TABLE#ShwEmptClls {
                 display: table; 
                 empty-cells: show;
                 cellspacing: 0;
                 cellpadding: 0; 
                 border: 0
                 {
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TR {align: center}
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TD1 {width: 115px; text-align: center}
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TD2 {width: 95px; text-align: center}
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TD3 {width: 95px; text-align: center}
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TD4 {width: 95px; text-align: center}
TABLE#ShwEmptClls.TD5 {width: 95px; text-align: center}
```

This should save you from having to add all of that inline mark-up you're currently using. Give it a try once you get the initial markup working for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply!!
1st solution works, but it is not feasible as would need to add null check at lots of places in class.
For 2nd solution:
Please let me know if I have added it correctly. It is still not working.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks again...
Ain't working though..:(
I have a feeling that I am making some silly syntax mistake...can you please have a look? I have corrected the original question and added these changes

Comment: You're applying other CSS that could easily be conflicting. I would look to see what `class="list"` contains and put all relevant CSS in your styleclass as I've shown it above. You simply have too many competing classes plus in-line CSS to say what's happening.

Comment: I am not able to find Class="list" details anywhere in my code or on internet

Comment: Do you have any static resources referenced on your page? Those could contain stylesheets, including ones for JS. Could also try just removing those additional classes you've specified. The browser will ignore them if it can't find them. Oh, open Chrome's Developer Tools and it will tell you where the CSS is coming from that's being applied!

Comment: Got it resolved through controller itself by putting some logic :)
However, thanks a lot for the help..I will keep investigating this issue further as curiosity later time.

Comment: Just as a note: the CSS solution will not work, because Visualforce does not even return the null values in the apex:repeat. It just skips over them. I.e. it will not even generate a <td> with a null value, it will just generate nothing.